# Testing Dojo with DOH without local Dojo installation

Tags: dojo, cross-domain, doh

I'm trying to work out how to use DOH to test Dojo modules if I don't install Dojo locally to my project. I'm working in Eclipse and ideally, I'd like something that I can run as part of a Maven build eventually. The Dojo package is 5-20Mb and I don't want to have it stashed in my source control system with each project if possible.

I've tried a few options with the runner.html test runner, but DOH is going to need to find a Dojo somewhere, and then it seems that modules will be found relative to that installation.

Having Dojo installed on my system but not in the project gives me a problem in trying to find the project relative to the location of the dojo.js file. The cross-domain protection prevents me serving up any kind of absolute path as it strips `:` characters. It also stops me using a Dojo installation served up on a different domain over http.

Is it necessary to have Dojo installed somewhere that I can then define a relative path from dojo.js to the roots of my modules? If not, how do I configure to get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tried this completely cross domain, but yes, you can define paths which may be enough to get you going.

We run our tests using a somewhat complicated deployment (to ensure we don't introduce accidental dojo/doh path dependencies), and our URL looks like this:

```
http://server/XXX/dev/dohpath/util/doh/runner.html?boot=../../../dojo/dojo.js&dojoUrl=../../../dojo/dojo.js&paths=doh,../dohpath/util/doh;mymodule,../../mymodule&testModule=full.test.module
```

That is, you fire up the runner, give it both 'boot' and 'dojoUrl' to tell it where Dojo itself lives, use 'paths' to tell DOH where it lives and how to find your own modules.

*blech*

Whether those relative paths can be made absolute successfuly, and whether it'll work cross-domain is an entirely different matter, I'm afraid. We'll be hitting that problem ourselves in a couple of months.

Comment: Where you ever able to get this to work?  I'm on 1.7 and can't get it to work with a cdn.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to do this with the runner located at http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/checkout/util/doh/runner.html and a gist.

The trick seems to be to use a path alias in the URL, and use a network-path reference URL (i.e. omit the URL scheme, URL starts with `//`).

I found this out while trying to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062265/how-to-check-if-function-throw-an-error-in-doh) without a local copy of DOH.

Here it is:

http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/checkout/util/doh/runner.html?testModule=aa&paths=aa,//gist.github.com/gitgrimbo/5406688/raw/e6bc4469ce72dfd6d50e61e885889cb915a3f66b/gistfile1