# How to check if function throw an error in DOH?

Tags: dojo, tdd, doh

I'm trying to check if a function throws error, and made this:

```
 define([
     'doh/runner',
     'app/Obj'
 ], function(
     doh,    
     Obj 
 ){
     doh.register('Test Obj exception', [
         function () {
             try {          
                 new Obj(); // should throw error
             } catch(e) {
                 doh.t(e, 'should give an error if no parameters given');               
             }
         }
 ]);
```

**Obj.js** file:

```
...
constructor: function (args){
  if (!args) { throw 'Error' }
  ...
}
...
```

But maybe where is some right method for this thing in Doh ? Can someone explain? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Can you tell us what is happening and what you want/expect to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want doh.assertError()

Example:

```
doh.assertError(TypeError, this.field, "setValue",
    [{
        CreatedOn: "March 10th, 2014"
    }],
    "setValue() on an invalid format should throw a TypeError");
```

Answer (score 0):

[This example test](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/checkout/util/doh/runner.html?testModule=aa&paths=aa,//gist.github.com/gitgrimbo/5406688/raw/e6bc4469ce72dfd6d50e61e885889cb915a3f66b/gistfile1) shows that DOH catches and displays an error correctly.

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/gitgrimbo/5406688) is the test, and contains this code:

```
var Obj = function () {
    if (arguments.length < 1) {
        throw 'Error - There are ' + arguments.length + ' arguments';
    }
};
define(["doh/runner"], function(doh){
    var tests = [
        function () {
            new Obj(); // wrong call
        }
    ];
    doh.register('Test Obj exception', tests);
});
```

The screenshot shows the 1 error, and the error msg from the `Error` thrown:

[image]

Comment: I think the OP was referring more to how to have DOH recognize that an error is being correctly throw (so passing a test). Is this possible? Thanks for your help here!

Comment: To clarify -- a passing test for an error correctly thrown in the code